# Can't boot into Windows with Grub | Debian install

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, debian, grub

I have Windows 7 installed on a second harddrive, and I just installed Debian on my first hard drive. Sadly, the bootloader (grub2) is not picking up my existing Windows installation, and I can't figure out why.

```
 # os-prober
```

returns nothing (eek).

Here's my disklayout:

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a3b4a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   389595713   194796833    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00058a73

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   959997951   479997952   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       959999998   976771071     8385537    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       960000000   976771071     8385536   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I tried forcing grub2 to pick up my windows install by editing the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file:

```
# cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom 
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry "Windows 7" {
insmod ntfs
set root='(hd1,0)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set BC9839B098396A52
chainloader +1
}
```

and then running `update-grub`, but that just says "BOOTMGR missing" when I try to select the Windows 7 entry in the grub menu. Does anyone have any suggestions? I really can't afford to reinstall Windows 7, so that would trully be a last resort :-(

Comment: `os-prober` needs ntfs support to auto-detect Windows, have you installed `ntfs-3g` ?

Comment: Yes, I have `ntfs-3g` installed.

Comment: Looks like your GRUB installation is clean, but your Windows bootloader is corrupted. How did you install W7 ? It usually comes as at least two partitions : a little one holding the bootloader and the main one. Can't see this little one on your installation.

Comment: Ah, good point. I guess I could use the Windows recovery disk, but then I suppose that would overwrite the grub installation :/. How would you suggest I approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Windows Bootloader is corrupted, you should try repairing it with a recovery disk.

As you have two hard drives, you can easily prevent any overwriting : simply disconnect your Linux HDD before booting on Windows recovery disk. This way, Windows will not interfere with Debian or GRUB in any way.

If you are lucky, Windows Recovery will be enough. But as you are missing a partition, it might not work. If not, you will probably have to re-install you windows (which won't be able to boot anyway). If it is the case, perform the Windows installation with your Linux HDD unplugged, again to avoid unwanted interferences.

Afterwards, plug it back in, boot on your Debian and run `update-grub`. If Windows recovery was successful, `os-prober` should find it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. (I can't upvote due to no reputation!)